# "Can't open a new thread" errors on Heroku

Tags: python, multithreading, heroku, threadpool, python-multithreading

I'm writing a Python script for web scraping purposes, and trying to implement a multi-threaded approach to get the work done faster. I'm using a [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) to set the maximum number of threads.

```py
from threading import current_thread
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

MAX_THREADS = 100

def process_user(user):
    # makes one or more network requests and returns the results
    return {"count": 123}

users = get_users_from_database() # gets user records from the database

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=MAX_THREADS) as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(process_user, row) for row in users]
    batch = []
    for index, future in enumerate(as_completed(futures)):
        result = future.result()
        batch.append(result)

        # store full batch or when there are no more left to store...
        if (len(batch) >= BATCH_SIZE) or (index + 1 >= len(futures)):
            insert_users(batch) # stores in the database
            batch = []
```

Heroku [says](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#process-thread-limits) their free tier dyno can run up to 256 threads.

However when I run the script on a free tier Heroku server, it seems to run fine with up to 10 threads, but when trying to run with more threads, the script just runs into "RuntimeError: can't start new thread" errors.

Is there away to use more than 10 threads? Do I need to upgrade tiers? Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to have been a memory issue. Scaling up the dynos allows more threads to be utilized.